# What is the purpose of restricting access to JRE library classes on AppEngine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I've recently been trying to use a few classes on AppEngine that are restricted (specifically `CookieManager` and its imports), presumably because they aren't on the [whitelist](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist).

What I can't seem to find out is why there are restricted classes in the first place. I can take the source code from a restricted class, copy and paste it in to my own package and everything works fine so what is the point in these class restrictions?

The cynic in me says Google wants to encourage code duplication just to charge more for storage, but can anyone enlighten me to any other reason why Google would arbitrarily say you can't access a class in the `java.*` package but you can access a class built from the exact same source in your own package?

Comment: can you provide names of this classes?

Comment: @IgorArtamonov `CookieManager` was one that I had to make my own copy with, along with some of the classes it imports.

Comment: You should include this into your question. I don't think its possible to answer this question "_in general_", because each restricted class has own reasons to exclude

Comment: @IgorArtamonov I've edited the question. The more general case that I'm really interested in though, is why restrict any class when the source code is available so re-implementation is trivial?

Comment: I guess you know the answer (don't believe your really think it's to charge for storage, additional class will cost you less that a cent a year). It's because it's shared VM, because of security, you shouldn't allowed to anything that can touch other apps under same VM. if you need unrestricted VM, then take a look at Managed VM

Comment: @IgorArtamonov I'm still not really understanding you. I can see why certain functionality like writing to the filesystem would be blocked at a low level. What I don't understand is why particular classes are restricted when there is nothing to stop me just copying the source code in to my own class.

Comment: we don't know internal architecture of App Engine server, if it's not excluded by mistake then there're something that can be broken because of this class, or maybe it references other restricted class. Also, by introducing your own copy of the class, you don't bring this class itself, now it's different class, with different package name, that just have same source code, or maybe just part of it

Comment: @IgorArtamonov Okay. You could be correct about it being due to some internal AppEngine weirdness. Maybe code that is in the `java` package is considered trusted somehow and copying it to my own package is safe from Google's perspective as it's no longer trusted code. I'm guessing this means that there are some operations that will fail when called, but it seems to work fine for what I'm doing. I asked the question more out of curiosity rather than any practical reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whitelist exists so that classes which provide code which can compromise the environment or applications in the environment cannot be executed. These range from operations which potentially allow  escaping the sandbox (i.e. Your application space) to gaining access to the machine, disk or network outside of the sandbox environment.
The container system Google use for GAE is not public, so it isn't clear what flavor these could take.

Classes in the JRE vary in age drastically, and many have odd behaviors and couplings, so it isn't always obvious why a class is blacklisted. For example, consider the coupling between a jdbc Driver and the DriverManager (not suggesting that it's a security flaw, just an unusual API and implementation in Java land). Presumably cookie manager might allow access to the information in other applications because of assumptions in the implementation that handles storage, for example.

As an example of how tricky some of these are to identify, here's an announcement from last year: [enter link description here](http://www.itnews.com.au/news/more-java-holes-found-in-google-app-engine-404095)

Comment: Thank you very much for providing more insight in to this. The link regarding vulnerabilities seems especially interesting since the report from the security company indicates that some classes are given increased privileges based on the package they are in. I guess this means either Google have decided `CookieManager` could allow a user to break out of the sandbox via its elevated permissions or they just take a better-safe-than-sorry approach and haven't bothered to whitelist it.